# Passing data through different window in javafxs

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my project structure.
[projectStructure][1]

and here are some more of the project.
MainController:

```
FileOpeniongFunction(){
    File selectedFile=fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    filePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath().toString();
    if(selectedFile !=null){
        mylistview.getItems().add(selectedFile.getName());
    }
    else {
    System.out.println("File is not valid");
    }
}

@FXML
private void unzipitems(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if(!filePath.isEmpty()){
        progressbox.display(filePath);
    }
}
```

And ProgressBoxController:

```
   public void display(String zipFilePath) throws IOException {

    Stage window = new Stage();
    Parent root = 
             FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/progress.fxml"));

    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    window.setScene(scene);
    window.showAndWait();

    unzipper.unzip(zipFilePath);

}
```

I want to work showAndWait and unzipper.unzip to work simultaneously. But one runs after another only. I tried to put unzipper.unzip() in initialize of ProgressBoxController but I can't get "filePath" to that controller.

Comment: `window.showAndWait()` shows the window and waits until it is closed before proceeding to the next line of code. So surely this is the expected behavior here. It's not really clear what the question is.

Comment: Will  `window.show()` work?

Comment: @sedrick ... no it doesn't work because i don't want users to interact with background window

Comment: @james ... i want unzip() to work in background while showAndWait does its work (i.e. while the another window is shown)

Comment: But as I said, `showAndWait` *blocks*. So `unzipper.unzip(...)` isn't even executed until the window is closed.

Comment: Could you use `window.show()` and disable the controls on the background window?